# Over versus overly

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

A few years ago, I read a grammar rule about the proper use of *over* versus *overly*. After searching, I can no longer find it. My husband says it is correct to add an LY anytime you want to describe a verb. He therefore says things, such as overly cook, overly eat, overly worked,etc. I am hearing other people use these words as well. I believe the compound words, overcook, overeat, etc. would be correct here. Not only does the added LY sound unnecessary, I believe there is a rule explaining the reason.

Comment: Some English colocations that appear to awkward in isolation can make sense when placed in an appropriate (textual) context. Would you mind expanding one or two of your  question's sample -ly phrases to full sentences?

Comment: Yes, I’m glad to provide a couple simple sentences.  As an example, the letters LY seem unnecessary, but I hear them used in the following sentences: Last Thanksgiving, I overly ate. However, the food was overly cooked. I believe she overly worked herself in preparing the food.

Answer (score 3):

The use of *overly* in the prototypical adverbial function (modifying a verb) is often at best archaic, especially with base forms. The compound verbs are indeed a far better choice.

It is however often used to premodify adjectives;

> **overly**: to an excessive degree : TOO
>
> - *But because of the many ways that the COVID-19 pandemic has upended life for people facing economic hardship, the earlier findings may be
>   overly optimistic for the current moment.* — Joya Misra, Quartz, 18
>   July 2021
>
> ......
>
> - *The Fuel’s 3-1 win over the Toronto Defiant Saturday afternoon wasn’t shocking or overly impressive.* — Sean Collins, Dallas News, 10
>   July 2021
>
> ......
>
> - *Critics say some American CEOs have become hostages of the Chinese Communist Party, which may be overly harsh.* — Andrew Stuttaford,
>   National Review, 9 July 2021

*Overly* is, on the other hand, quite often used with past participle forms of verbs followed by prepositional phrases (/multi-word verbs? 'be fixated on ...'?):

> - *Even with those cash incentives on the line, the Sun weren’t overly fixated on the implications of Friday’s game.* — Alexa Philippou,
>   courant.com, 9 July 2021
>
> ......
>
> - *The office became overly focused on intelligence originating from the federal intelligence community at the expense of its unique
>   ability to capitalize on relationships with non-federal law
>   enforcement entities.* — Geneva Sands, CNN, 9 July 2021
>
> ......
>
> - *White men from the financial sector and big businesses continue to be overly represented on the boards overseeing the 12 regional Federal
>   Reserve Banks, despite some progress on improving the boards’
>   diversity, a new report said.* — Michael S. Derby, WSJ, 9 July 2021

[all quoted material from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overly)]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the various uses of the word overly. While I see the ly is considered archaic and compound words  are the preferred choice, I am still wondering about an actual grammar rule. I found the rule I am referring to, buried in a grammar message board online a while back. I recall him pointing out that it was a rule which has not been taught for  quite a while.

Comment: A rule that 'hasn't been taught for a while' is almost certainly not a rule, and may well never have been one. Old grammars / grammar teachers often seemed a law unto themselves (but not to others).